# Are there examples of mathematical systems that reflect the worldview of the culture they are from?

Tags: mathematics, mathematics-social-history, numbers

By this I mean, are there systems of numbers, counting, sorting.. or even higher level mathematical concepts that reflect a culture's worldview? Did some cultures not develop certain math concepts because of their worldview?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps distantly related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/101052/454

Comment: Basically mathematics in every culture was influenced by that culture: Greek math, Chinese math, Hebrew math, Indian math, Modern European math, etc.